# Can not implement NormalizableInterface on Symfony 2.0.9

Tags: php, symfony

I´m tryng to implement the *Symfony\Component\Serializer\Normalizer\NormalizableInterface* using Symfony 2.0.9.

I added the implementation like this:

```
class MRoute implements NormalizableInterface{
...
public function normalize($object, $format = null)
{
     $points = array();
     foreach ($this->getPoints() as $point) {
         $points[] = $point->normalize();
     }
    return array(
        'id' => $this->getId(),
        'name' => $this->getName(),
        'points' => $points

    );
}

/**
 * @see
 */
function denormalize(NormalizerInterface $normalizer, $data, $format = null)
{
    if (isset($data['name']))
    {
        $this->setName($data['name']);
    }

    if (isset($data['id']))
    {
        $this->setId($data['id']);
    }
}
```

But when I try to acces the web service I get an error like this:

Fatal error: Declaration of MyGIS\GISBundle\Entity\MRoute::normalize() must be compatible with that of Symfony\Component\Serializer\Normalizer\NormalizableInterface::normalize() in C:\NetbeansProjects\mroute_rest_service\src\MyGIS\GISBundle\Entity\MRoute.php on line 16

I opened the Symfony\Component\Serializer\Normalizer\NormalizableInterface.php and the signatures match.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The interface in v2.0.9 is quite different from what you have pasted here:
https://github.com/symfony/symfony/blob/v2.0.9/src/Symfony/Component/Serializer/Normalizer/NormalizableInterface.php

It looks like you have implemented the 2.1 interface, which is totally different:
https://github.com/symfony/symfony/blob/master/src/Symfony/Component/Serializer/Normalizer/NormalizableInterface.php

If you are in fact using 2.1 (the master branch) you need to add a `use` statement for `NormalizerInterface`.

```
use Symfony\Component\Serializer\Normalizer\NormalizerInterface;
```

Comment: Thank so much. The problem was I was using an example from [SymfPony ](http://symfpony-project.org/) for web services and it must have been using a previous version. Switched the signatures to match exactly the 2.0.9 NormalizableInterface.php and the problem was solved.